# Unable to query data using like with lots of special characters(%) in MySQL

Tags: sql

I inserted the value  below  to a users table,

```
~\`!@%23$%^%26*()-=_+{}[]|\\:;\"'<>?,./
```

then query it with like, got nothing , however the `=` works correct, why the `LIKE` clause doesn't work please?

### Prepare data

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into users(name) values('~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./'); 
insert into users(name) values('test');
```

### Query

```
select * from users where name like '%~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./%'; // Got nothing

select * from users where name='~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./';  // Got the inserted data
```

Even though I escape the `%` and `_`, it still not work

```
select * from users where name like '%~`!@\%23$\%^\%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./%'; // Still got nothing
```

### What expected

When execute

```
select * from users where name like '%~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./%'; // Got nothing
```

It supposed to  get this record only

```
~\`!@%23$%^%26*()-=_+{}[]|\\:;\"'<>?,./
```

Comment: please mark your database type

Comment: @vidyVideni I have added a solution for MySQL, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use concat like this (not sure MySQL or another DB type there, but the principle is the same):

```
select * from users 
where name like
'%' || '~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./' || '%';
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4527ea8cc29bfdde158ee2b972468e4c)

**upd.** Due to a new issue with new rows, I got fixed my code with **`ESCAPE`**.

```
select *
from users 
where name like 
 '%~`!@%23$#%^#%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./%' --<< escape # before % character
escape '#';
```

Here's [new dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6bbb8d6256431092b7907a02f33706f)

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I just want to add in SQL Server DB you need to use + instead of ||. But the OP seems to do not use SQL Server, so this should work.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as expected, it will return others records not matching ~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=_+{}[]|\\:;\"'<>?,./

Comment: @JonasMetzler please try to insert another raw,  for example ,  insert into users(name) values('test');

Comment: It seems the MySQL treat || as or, not concat string, I tried the CONCAT('%', '~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./', '%') got no lucky.

Comment: @vidyvideni The reason is that your string contains a % sign, which is compiled as "a set of any characters of any length". Need to escape this character in the query, see the updated code

Comment: @Jesusbrother  haha, I tried the escape clause before, I didn't expect, we need to use both  `#` and `\\` to escape.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use INSTR:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE INSTR(name, '~`!@%23$%^%26*()-=\_+{}[]|\\\\:;\\"\'<>?,./') > 0
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works, can you also explain why the like one doesn't work please.

Comment: I'm no friend of using like for such complex conditions and don't use it very often. Maybe it's possible somehow to do this using like (I assumed the answer above should do), but I think this is some kind of strange syntax and INSTR is easier.

Comment: Great workaround,  In this case the performance for both  is same. The above answer doesn't work as expected, because it returns all records.

Comment: the above works now